# Vb.net application session timeout is not working using web.config, Global.asax and Application Pool Idle time. Session-cookies are using in app

Tags: vb.net, wcf, session-cookies, session-timeout

I need to implement session timeout in vb.net application. It's using wcf services.

I tried to implement session timeout using web.config, Global.asax and in IIs session state and in App pool both. Nothing works. Application is using sessioncookie and it stores in Sql Server DB.

Please help me to implement sessiontimeout.

Comment: Does [Session.Timeout not working correctly in ASP Classic / IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31994918/1115360) help?

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are stored based on the SQL database you are using. So you can use the following configuration code:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState mode="SQLServer"
      sqlConnectionString="Integrated Security=SSPI;data 
        source=SampleSqlServer;"
        timeout="20" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The unit of timeout is minutes.