# Session based Shopping Cart gets clobbered

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7, session-cookies, shopping-cart, windows-server-2012

We have several eCommerce sites built with Classic ASP. Our customers complain that their shopping carts get emptied for no apparent reason AND that they are moving quickly through the site.

Our shopping cart uses the customer's sessionid and stores their items in a shoppingcart table in the database. What I suspect is happening is that the sessionid is getting changed, hence, no record of items in the shoppingcart table for that new sessionid.

This is on a Windows 2012 server/IIS7 and the `ASP`->`Session Properties`->`Session Properties`->`New ID On Secure Connection` is set to `False`.

So, apparently, IIS7 sometimes resets the sessionID and kills the cart. This happens more frequently when someone is putting LOTS of things into their cart, hence, more exposure to this IIS7 issue.

Is there a better way to handle a shopping cart? For instance, would I be better off placing a cookie in their browser with a unique identifier, then use that instead of the sessionID to retain the customer's shopping cart?

Cookies get clobbered too on occasion -- not sure which direction to turn, lost in the woods.

Comment: Check the App Pool recycle settings, even if you have Session Timeout set to 20 minutes there are various settings in the App Pool that will override this.

Comment: You dont have to use the session.  If you are storing the items in a table anywhy then use the key from the head record for the order.  Of course you will have to pass this from page to page.   To be honest I avoid session or application level storage when ever I can, which is almost always.  Use your own keys and identifiers then you will always have better control IMO

Comment: I provide some advice on how to deal with this here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/22983431/692942.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Session Timeout in Classic ASP website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22980202/session-timeout-in-classic-asp-website)

Comment: I experienced this behaviour when using "Maximum Worker Processes">1 in IIS Application Pool settings. Sessions would get lost rather randomly and more so under increased server load.